# Python Discord bot non caps sensitive

Tags: python, discord

How can i make my python discord bot caps non sensitive.

```
if message.content.startswith('$doge'):
        price('dogecoin')

        await dembed('Dogecoin', 'https://www.shareicon.net/data/2015/09/14/101012_doge_512x512.png', message.id)

        print('Dogecoin:', rprice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `message.content` is a string, we can use the `lower` method to get the lowercase string.

```py
if message.content.lower().startswith('$doge'):
   # do stuff
```

### References and further reading:

- [strings](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp)